# Has anyone managed to add custom icons into Ionic in Windows?

Tags: windows, ionic-framework, ionicons

I refer the [instructions here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionicons)

What I did (on Windows):

1. Install fontforge through web instead of 'brew'
2. Install SASS through Ruby GEM
3. Place my-icon.svg inside src/ (of the ionicons-master)
4. Run the python ./builder/generate.py

I think I am very closed. Until i saw this error message:
[image]

**windowsError: The system cannot find the file specified**

And I think I get even closer when I saw the last post of this [link](https://github.com/driftyco/ionicons/issues/353)
But, I don't get what it means. I downloaded the .exe but it doesn't work.

Is it the python build only meant for MAC? Has anyone managed to make this work in Windows?